# Real valued eigenvalues in GAP?

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, gap

I have a matrix in GAP, and I want its real valued eigenvalues. (Or rational approximations of them, of course.) As far as I can tell Eigenvalues(Rationals,A) only gives me the rational eigenvalues. This seems like a silly question but I couldn't find documentation for this anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely not something GAP will excel at; since good algorithms for eigenvalue computation do not use the characteristic polynomial, but rather decompositions (QR, LR, ...).

Here's an example of how to do it with the current features of GAP:

```
gap> m := [[2,1],[1,1]];
[ [ 2, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ] ]
gap> Eigenvalues(Rationals,m); # are the rational roots?
[  ]
gap> Eigenvalues(CyclotomicField(5),m);
[ -E(5)-2*E(5)^2-2*E(5)^3-E(5)^4, -2*E(5)-E(5)^2-E(5)^3-2*E(5)^4 ]
gap> CharacteristicPolynomial(m);
x_1^2-3*x_1+1
gap> c := CoefficientsOfUnivariatePolynomial(last);
[ 1, -3, 1 ]
gap> RootsFloat(List(c,Float));
[ 0.381966, 2.61803 ]
```

You may also use high-precision packages within GAP, if the package "Float" is installed (this comes precompiled in some GAP distributions):

```
gap> LoadPackage("float");
true
gap> SetFloats(MPFR,1000); # 1000 bits
gap> MPFR.constants.VIEW_DIG := 100;; # show 100 digits
gap> RootsFloat(List(c,Float));
[ .3819660112501051517954131656343618822796908201942371378645513772947395371810975502927927958106088625e0,
  .2618033988749894848204586834365638117720309179805762862135448622705260462818902449707207204189391137e1 ]
```

Note that complex roots can also be computed by Float; in fact, they are what RootsFloat returns by default when the Float package is loaded:

```
gap> m := PermutationMat((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),10);
[ [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ], [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]
gap> Eigenvalues(CyclotomicField(5),m);
[ 1, -1, E(5), E(5)^2, E(5)^3, E(5)^4, -E(5)^4, -E(5)^3, -E(5)^2, -E(5) ]
gap> c := CoefficientsOfUnivariatePolynomial(CharacteristicPolynomial(m));
[ -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
gap> RootsFloat(List(c,Float));
[ .809017e0+.587785e0ⅈ, -.809017e0+.587785e0ⅈ, -.309017e0-.951057e0ⅈ, .809017e0-.587785e0ⅈ,
  .309017e0+.951057e0ⅈ, -.1e1, .309017e0-.951057e0ⅈ, .1e1, -.309017e0+.951057e0ⅈ,
  -.809017e0-.587785e0ⅈ ]
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I am getting the following error when I run RootsFloat(List(c,Float));.

"Error, no method found! For debugging hints type ?Recovery from NoMethodFound
Error, no 1st choice method found for `RootsFloatOp' on 2 arguments called from
RootsFloatOp( l, l[1] ) called from
Error( no_method_found ); called from
RootsFloatOp( l, l[1] ) called from
<function "RootsFloat">( <arguments> )
 called from read-eval loop at line 2 of *errin*"

Does this mean anything to you? The float package is installed (I can run List(c,Float) ), but I get a "fail" message when I run LoadPackage("float");

Thanks!

Comment: `LoadPackage("float")` returning `fail` means that the package is not installed. The other command works because `Float` is a function provided by the core GAP system. Float package needs compilation, see its README. If you can't compile it, better to discuss this in [GAP Support](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/People/supportgroup.html) - the comments are not convenient to paste error messages and may not be seen at all.

Answer (score 3):

GAP does not have the real numbers (or approximate real numbers) as a data type, so it cannot factor polynomials over the reals.

In some cases, working over a suitable cyclotomic field or a formal algebraic extension might help.

What I would try is to first calculate the `CharacteristicPolynomial` of the matrix in question, and then factor it over the rationals, this will give you an idea what field extension is needed.

Comment: After calculating the characteristic polynomial, look also at the [Float package](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/float-0.6.2/doc/chap3.html#X788CDC24834012D7), which may help.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Thanks. Do you happen to know the float command to use? It isn't listed there.

Comment: Try `RootsFloat` - this is used in the example in a [test file](https://github.com/gap-system/float/blob/master/tst/polynomials.tst) for the package, and also in the example from the link in my previous comment. If this will not help, I suggest to ask the package author directly.

Comment: P.S. The function `RootsFloat` is actually an undocumented GAP function from `lib/float.gi`, not from the package, so you should handle it with care. I will check later whether it should be documented, or it is assumed to be installed as a method for some documented operation.