# Real roots of a polynomial in GAP, and RootsFloat function

Tags: polynomials, roots, gap

Is there a way in GAP to calculate the roots of a polynomial, say $x^2-2$, as real numbers? I know I can express the roots as cyclotomic numbers, but then (real) cyclotomic numbers are not ordered as reals (see https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap18.html, Sect. 18.3), and this is a problem for me. Of course, a method to transform real cyclotomics into reals with usual order is good as well.

I see from "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358173/real-valued-eigenvalues-in-gap" that the powerful function *RootsFloat* exists and is contained in **lib/float.gi**, but I don't know how to "import" this function.

Comment: I do not think that GAP is designed for such problems. In this case I suggest to use a tool like PARI/GP.

Comment: This operation is built into GAP, but only as a placeholder. It is filled with life only by the "floats" package, which provides access to various implementations of floating point numbers; for some of them, `RootsFloat` methods are provided. Unfortunately its manual https://gap-packages.github.io/float/doc/chap0.html is rather sparse on information. You may want to contact its authors and/or submit an issue to get help at https://github.com/gap-packages/float/issues